# D3 Interpolate Line Chart on Time Axes

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I have a pretty basic line chart I'm using to plot some data on based on time.  This is all working fine however the problem I need to address is when the plots along the time axes are very close.

Consider the following data points:

```
{ "Id": 101, x:15, y: 10, "OriginDt": "2012-12-01T18:49:06"}
{ "Id": 101, x:15, y: 10, "OriginDt": "2012-12-02T28:49:06"}
{ "Id": 101, x:15, y: 10, "OriginDt": "2012-12-03T18:49:06"}
{ "Id": 101, x:15, y: 10, "OriginDt": "2012-12-04T08:10:06"}
{ "Id": 101, x:15, y: 10, "OriginDt": "2012-12-04T09:21:06"}
{ "Id": 101, x:15, y: 10, "OriginDt": "2012-12-04T11:32:06"}
```

For the first 3 points the chart looks fine but as soon as it gets to data that occurs within a short space of time the data starts to get bunched up and very hard to appreciate in the chart.

I've been trying to find a sample online that deals with something like this but haven't found it yet.

I've tried using the basic interpolation commands on the axes but these don't work.

How can I change my axes:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .tickSize(-width).tickPadding(10)
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
```

To "spread out" the points in these situations?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly, but it sounds like you want the time scale (ie "milliseconds per pixel") to vary from one region of the line chart to the next, depending on the density of the data. Is that right? If so, this can be done by setting the scale's `domain()` and `range()` to be arrays with more than just two elements as is the usual case.

Comment: Yes you are right in terms of the requirements and now that you mention the scales approach that does make sense.  I've done similar with scales elsewhere ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a comment but I don't have the necessary reputation.

You might want to look into [cartesian fisheye distortion](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/#cartesian)

Comment: That is indeed very interesting.  Thanks Justin!